# Drupal: modifying a template without hacking the module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to edit an invoice template in Drupal (both php template and css).

I've copied pasted the file in my theme folder, as I usually do to override for blocks and pages templates, but it didn't work.

This is the template customer.itpl.php inside **Ubercart/uc_orders/templates** folder.

How can I override it without hacking the ubercart module ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This template is not the normal Drupal template. In order to change it, you should create a copy of the template in the same folder (Ubercart/uc_orders/templates) and make your changes. It will show up as an option in the settings page (`/admin/store/settings/orders/edit`) where you specify which template to use for showing the invoice.

Answer (score 1):

[devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer/) is good at providing template suggestions for you. Sometimes modules uses a special naming convention.

If that doesn't help you can add your own template suggestion in a preprocess function for the template. See [this post on d.o](http://drupal.org/node/223440) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the ubercart docs](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/developer/246/invoice_system) you should be able to specify which template files you want to use.